# Vue JS 3 binding class does not update the class

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

HTML Section where i want to activate the mobile section in two spots

```
    <i @click="mobileClick" :class="[{ 'bi-x': menuOpen }, { 'bi-list': !menuOpen },'mobile-nav-toggle', 'bi']"></i>
```

JS functions called on click to switch the classes

```
setup(){

let menuOpen=  false

  const mobileClick = () =>{
  menuOpen = !menuOpen
  console.log(menuOpen)
   }
 return{mobileClick,  menuOpen}
}
```

the boolean updates on click but the classes do not... Do I have to re-render or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property should be  defined as a `ref` which is accessed by `value` field in your script :

```
import {ref} from 'vue';
export default {

 setup(){
    
    const menuOpen=  ref(false)

     const mobileClick = () =>{
     menuOpen.value = !menuOpen.value
     console.log(menuOpen.value)
    }
    return{mobileClick,  menuOpen}
   }

}
```

in template no need to use `value` field :

```
<i @click="mobileClick" :class="[{ 'bi-x': menuOpen }, { 'bi-list': !menuOpen },'mobile-nav-toggle', 'bi']"></i>
```